# Video Volume Not Adjusting

Tags: javascript, video

Video loads and plays, but volume is at 100%. I want it at 20%. Code to adjust isn't working. Ideas?

```
<script>
function setvolume() {
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.volume = 0.2;
}
window.onload = setvolume;
</script>

<video src="{!-ASSETSPATH-!}External%20Files/Hurricane%20Home.m4v" autoplay="autoplay id="myVideo"></video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the video element is ready before setting the volume. Try hooking up on the canplay event it emits or one of the earlier events.

Comment: No canplay event is set (not wanted). There is no earlier event to hook up to.

Comment: Ok. Your snippet doesn't use the canplay event. Maybe it's better if you provide the code that does.

Comment: So there is no other way to set the volume unless I set up a canplay event?

Comment: Both the audio and video elements in HTML5 are implemented very differently on different browsers. My experience is that the safest way is to hook up on the canplay event, but you may experience that not all browsers respect the setting. Safari and Explorer are the worst by far.